# android - Http request returns empty JSONArray from ASHX

Tags: android, http

The ashx in the server send this response:

```
[
    {
        "Dominio": "123",
        "CoTransporte": 1,
        "Descripcion": "Suzuki Fun Negro 5 Puertas",
        "Anio": "2005",
        "Titular": "Jorge Gonzalez",
        "CoDocumento": 96,
        "Documento": "31541344",
        "Domicilio": "Av. Santa Fe 2564",
        "Localidad": "Capital Federal",
        "Seguro": "Mapfre Aconcagua",
        "Poliza": "678542134",
        "Propio": false
    },
    {
        "Dominio": "UJE666",
        "CoTransporte": 1,
        "Descripcion": "Renault Fuego Marron 3 Puertasq",
        "Anio": "1986",
        "Titular": "Mauro Almendros",
        "CoDocumento": 96,
        "Documento": "31541344",
        "Domicilio": "Av. Santa Fe 2564",
        "Localidad": "Capital Federal",
        "Seguro": "Mapfre Aconcagua",
        "Poliza": "678542134",
        "Propio": false
    }
]
```

and this is my android code to process the response:

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(this.GetVehiculosHandlerURL());
            String json  = "";

            try {
                // Add your data
                //httppost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dominio", dominio));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
                if (ent != null)
                {
                    InputStream instream  = ent.getContent();
                    String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
                    JSONArray j = new JSONArray(result);
                    System.out.println(j.length());
                    instream.close();

                }
```

When i try to get the array lenght the value is zero. Please somebody help me to find my error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you get as a result (String result)? also are you sure you need HttpPost and not HttpGet?

Comment: Either HTTP method should work. I would suggest using the [EntityUtils.toString](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) method. Pass it the response entity.